# MySQL Server error: Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, zend-db

I have received this error when trying to connect to my server via 8443 portal:

```
ERROR: Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (Abstract.php:144)
```

All my website are down. 123-reg technicians indicate that it is a MySQL problem but the error logs in `/var/log/mysqld.log`, `/var/log/mysql.err` and `/var/log/mysql.log` appear blank when I view them with `tail -f`.

The support technician can't help any further and I feel stuck. Please help.

Comment: I am using Linux, Ubuntu & Plesk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technician indicated that it was due to an overload of information on the server: too many backups being made! Thanks for your help though.

I found the error in another error log which helped:
In `/var/log/mysql/error.log` I found:

`[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs`

Answer (score 0):

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Failed to database connection.

MySQL is running?

> [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600
>   secs

I think your disk is full...

Please check Binary log file.

Comment: When I try  `service mysql status`   i get   `mysql stop/waiting`,  `ps aux | grep mysql` creates `root     16317  0.0  0.0   7628   908 pts/0    R+   10:19   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql` and `mysqladmin -u root -p status` creates `'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!` but the socket exists: because `grep -i socket /etc/psa/psa.conf` creates 
`MYSQL_SOCKET /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`